# Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String' in Xcode7

Tags: swift, xcode7

I just upgraded to Swift 2.0 And Xcode 7 Beta and I am getting the error:

**Cannot assign a value of type 'String' to a value of type 'String'**

while writing:

```
 var string = (change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]) as! String?
```

Comment: I would file a radar. The bang in the `as!` seems necessary because you're forcing a downcast. But you also want to include the `?` to indicate it's a `String` type that *may not have a value.* This is different from (1) a `String` that will always have a value, and from (2) a generic type (`AnyObject`). I see `String?` as a very distinct, third option.

Comment: Swift's error codes are really, really bad sometimes. Treat the error message as the compiler saying "Duh... I don't understand!" and proceed from there. Patricks suggestion of optional binding is worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `as! String?` part is the problem.

You should probably be doing this:

```
if let string = change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey] as? String {
    // Do something with `string`
}
```